# My audioclip stops as soon as it plays unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DayNightController : MonoBehaviour {
public AudioSource daySong;
public AudioSource nightSong;
public Light sun;
public float secondsInFullDay = 120f;
[Range(0,1)]
public float currentTimeOfDay = 0;
[HideInInspector]
public float timeMultiplier = 1f;

float sunInitialIntensity;

void Start() {
    sunInitialIntensity = sun.intensity;

}

void Update() {
    UpdateSun();

    currentTimeOfDay += (Time.deltaTime / secondsInFullDay) * timeMultiplier;

    if (currentTimeOfDay >= 1) {
        currentTimeOfDay = 0;
    }
    if(currentTimeOfDay > 0.5){
        daySong.Stop();
        nightSong.Play(0);
    }
    if(currentTimeOfDay < 0.5){
        daySong.Play(0);
        nightSong.Stop();
    }
}

void UpdateSun() {
    sun.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler((currentTimeOfDay * 360f) - 90, 170, 0);

    float intensityMultiplier = 1;
    if (currentTimeOfDay <= 0.23f || currentTimeOfDay >= 0.75f) {
        intensityMultiplier = 0;
    }
    else if (currentTimeOfDay <= 0.25f) {
        intensityMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp01((currentTimeOfDay - 0.23f) * (1 / 0.02f));
    }
    else if (currentTimeOfDay >= 0.73f) {
        intensityMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp01(1 - ((currentTimeOfDay - 0.73f) * (1 / 0.02f)));
    }

    sun.intensity = sunInitialIntensity * intensityMultiplier;
}
}
```

So when the time hits that point of the if command, I hear the song but its stops 1 sec after playing, the audio clips are over 2min, I dont know why this do is it, It activates that if command but then stops, Sorry for being a noob but I need help because the game I'm making means the world to me, More Info:
What Im thinking, it activates the if command then tries the next one and stops the audio clip, Would it help if the number [current time] be rounded?

Comment: Use `else if` for the remaining if statements like in your function. If only to save on the resources of skipping that code. If it finds a match no use spending CPU time (Albeit very little) to evaluate the remaining if statements.

Comment: What is the value of `secondsInFullDay` in your inspector? It might differ from `120` making a "day" shorter maybe?

Comment: It surprises me that you actually hear it playing for 1 second ... afaik everytime you call `Play` the clip is restarted. You should rather check for exact values and use `PlayOneShot` instead

Answer (score 0):

You are going to call `Play` at every frame. You only need to call play on the frame that switches between night and day

```
void Update() {
    UpdateSun();

    bool isDay = currentTimeOfDay <= 0.5;
    currentTimeOfDay += (Time.deltaTime / secondsInFullDay) * timeMultiplier;
    if (currentTimeOfDay >= 1) {
        currentTimeOfDay = 0;
    }
    bool willBeDay = currentTimeOfDay <= 0.5;

    if(isDay && !willBeDay){
        daySong.Stop();
        nightSong.Play(0);
    }
    else if(!isDay && willBeDay){
        nightSong.Stop();
        daySong.Play(0);
    }
}
```